# how to export vertex color node in blender?

Tags: export, vertex-colors

I export a .fbx file with vertex colors node in blender, then i import the same fbx in blender, but the vertex colors node disappear, i have to add and link the node again, how can i save the vertex colors node in blender?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!
[image]

Comment: FBX doesn't store vertex color information. If you need it for external application, you have to bake it in texture

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541